# I can't build wheel for opencv on ARM Architecture

Tags: arm, python-wheel, opencv, python

When running that command to build opencv for python on ARM architecture

```
pip wheel --wheel-dir=./ opencv-python
```

I get that error

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv-python
```

Although, when running it on my pc (amd64) it runs very well. So, Is there a different naming for opencv for ARM architecture ?

Answer (score 0):

The Python Package Index (PyPi) doesn't support Arm wheels so package maintainers cannot upload pre-built packages for the Arm architecture. If you look at the wheels in the table at the bottom of [python-opencv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python/3.3.0.10) on PyPI you will notice they're all for x86, what you can also notice is this package *only* ships wheels and no source, therefore there is nothing to fallback on for other architectures.

As an example, if you look at the [numpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy/1.13.3) package you'll notice it also ships the source, so although there is no wheel the package can still be built from source on Arm.

You're only option is to clone the source [here](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python) and build manually. It might also be worth creating an issue on the issue tracker as they should be providing source.

It's also worth noting that [warehouse](https://pypi.org/) the successor to PyPI will [support](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/2003) Arm wheels.

Comment: As of version 4.3.0, opencv-python ships with source files.

Comment: numpy 1.19 has pre-built aarch64 (ARM) wheels, so this answer is out of date.